# Using pushMatrix(), popMatrix(), translate(), and rotate()

Tags: rotation, processing, translate

I have a program that draws a flower with 4 petals to the screen where ever you click. Instead of redoing the petals one at a time I was just going to attempt to rotate the flower by a quarter turn and have it overlay the first flower, so it appears to have 8 petals. The problem is that it draws the second flower some distance away from the first in the x and y direction, but as I get closer to (0,0) they get closer to overlapping (and do at (0, 0)). I'm not sure why this is happening and would appreciate any help. I'm using Processing 3 for this program.

```java
int c_center = 15;
int c_petal = 20;
int petalsize = 70;
color rcol;

void setup(){
  fullScreen();
  background(0);
}

void draw(){
  rcol = color(random(255), random(255), random(255));
}

void mouseClicked(){
  pushMatrix();
  flower();
  translate(mouseX, mouseY);
  rotate(PI/4);
  flower();
  popMatrix();
}

void flower(){
  //left petal
  make_petal(mouseX - (petalsize - c_petal), mouseY, petalsize, c_petal);
  //right petal
  make_petal(mouseX + (petalsize - c_petal), mouseY, petalsize, c_petal);
  //top petal
  make_petal(mouseX, mouseY - (petalsize - c_petal), c_petal, petalsize);
  //bottom petal
  make_petal(mouseX, mouseY + (petalsize - c_petal), c_petal, petalsize);
  //flower center
  fill(random(255), random(255), random(255));
  ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, c_center, c_center);
}

void make_petal(int a, int b, int c, int d){
  fill(rcol);
  ellipse(a, b, c, d);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing two styles of drawing together: your `flower()` function uses `mouseX` and `mouseY` to determine where to draw the petals, but then you're also calling `translate(mouseX, mouseY);`. So you're drawing petals relative to the mouse, but then moving the entire canvas by the mouse position, and then drawing more petals relative to the mouse again.

Instead, you probably want to only use one style of drawing. Specifically, you probably don't want your `flower()` function to care about the mouse position. Treat it like a "stamp" that draws things around the origin at `0,0`. Then move the origin by calling `translate()` and rotate the stamp by calling `rotate()`.

Comment: Thank you. I think I better understand how the `translate()` function works.

Comment: I do have one more thing to ask. If I wanted to move a object around the screen(changing it's x and y position by some value), how could I translate that in order for the object to spin continuously like a wheel while it moves around the screen?

Comment: @philxyz Generally you should ask follow-up questions in their own posts. But basically you would do the same thing you're currently doing with `mouseX` and `mouseY`, only you would use variables that you create and change over time.

Answer (score 0):

I corrected the code thanks to feedback, so it works now in case anyone is interested. I condensed it a little by just making one petal then rotating it through a loop.

```java
int c_center = 20;
int c_petal = int(random(5, 15));
int petalsize = int(random(30, 60));
color rcol;

void setup(){
  fullScreen();
  background(0);
}

void draw(){
  rcol = color(random(255), random(255), random(255));
}

void mouseClicked(){
  pushMatrix();
  translate(mouseX, mouseY);
  for(int r = 0; r < 360; r+=5){
  rotate(radians(r));
  flower();
  }
  popMatrix();
}

void flower(){
  //petal
  make_petal(0, 0 - (petalsize - c_petal), c_petal, petalsize);

  //flower center
  fill(random(255), random(255), random(255));
  ellipse(0, 0, c_center, c_center);
}

void make_petal(int a, int b, int c, int d){
  fill(rcol);
  ellipse(a, b, c, d);
}
```